# Domain of the laplace transform of $\cos(\omega t)$

Tags: laplace-transform

In my notes, it says that if $|f(t)| \leq e^{At}$ for some constant $A$, then the domain of the laplace transform of $f$ is $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\mathrm{Re}(z)>\mathrm{Re}(A)\}$.

Find the domain of the Laplace transform of $\cos(\omega t)$
where $\omega\in\mathbb{R}$.
So, since $|\cos(\omega t)| \leq 1 = e^{0t}$, then I would expect that the domain of the Laplace transform is the right-hand side of the complex plane.

However, I get a different result doing this:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(f(t)) :=& \int_0^\infty \cos (\omega t)e^{-zt}\ dt \\ =& \mathrm{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{i\omega t}e^{-zt}\ dt\right) \\ =& \mathrm{Re}\left(\left[\frac{e^{-t(z-i\omega)}}{z-iw}\right]_{0}^\infty  \right)
\end{align}$$
which converges iff $\mathrm{Re}(z-iw)>0\iff \mathrm{Re}(z) > w$

Comment: Isn't $\operatorname{Re}(i\omega) = 0$?

Comment: My bad, so the technique of bounding the function by its maximum (say $M = e^{\log(M)}$) to conclude that the domain is $\mathrm{Re}(z)> \mathrm{Re}(\log(M))$ is equivalent to seeing when it converges?